# Failing to negate case 'qwe' with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

What's wrong? I'm trying to exclude `text("123", qwe);` case, but it matches

```
text\([^,]+,\s*(?!qwe)[^\)]*\);
```

How I can make it accepts only function with second parameter not `"qwe"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text\([^,]+,\s*(?:(?!\bqwe\b)[^\s)]*)\);
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/12

Your regex `text([^,]+,\s*(?!qwe)[^)]*);` say that after captruing `text("123",` capture `space` which is not followd by `qwe`.But after that your regex `[^)]*` captures all including space.If you include `[^)\s]*`  then it wont be able to cpature and it will pass.See here

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/13

But this will pass only if there is a `space`.If there is not space your logic will fail.So to be foolproof check after evry `character` for the lookahead by using `(?:(?!\bqwe\b)[^\s)]*`

Comment: That works thanks! But I read a lot of manuals, never was used this construction, I will learn regexes carefully